# SwiftUI List updating slowly

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a `SwiftUI` List, which has thousands of items. Each item is as such:

```
class Item: Codable, Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var prop1 = ""
    var prop2 = ""
}
```

Now I do this:

```
List(store.items.indices, id: \.self) { index in
    DetailView(item: self.$store.items[index])
}.id(UUID())
```

I iterate the `indicies` because I have to pass a `Binding` to the `DetailView`.

Now the `DetailView` has `TextFields` attached to the `Item`'s properties.

When `DetailView` changes an `Item`'s properties, it causes the `List` to refresh **ALL** of the items, which I dont want.

Also, it's still important that when one of those properties changes, the main view is updated, because on macOS, the main view is still visible even when you click on one of the items.

**My question is how to make it so that whenever an `Item` passed in from the `List` changes, only update that row?**

I also tried a solution mentioned where I use a `LazyVStack`, and it fixes the performance issue, but I use the `List` inside of a `NavigationView`, and the `LazyVStack` doesn't seem to support that.

Any suggestions  are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Would you show complete standalone demo for that? and point version of env. where you see the issue?

Comment: Using a ScrollView with a LazyVStack will help eliminate some overhead of List if you aren't using the features it specifically provides. Lists in SwiftUI are not fully performant yet.

Comment: I would also say you should review the Published, State and Binding modifiers you use in self.$store since the whole UI updates on every change of these properties. Limit these modifiers as much as possible while keeping functionality

Answer (score 2):

Remove `.id(UUID())` from the List.

By default, List diffs changes and only updates the affected rows. For very large data sets, that `.id(UUID())` trick is used to force the whole List to reload when something changes, which may be faster than trying to diff the large dataset. It doesn’t sound like you need it, so it’s actually worse to include it unnecessarily.

Edit: I don’t think binding to the array by index is the problem, but it is unusual and may bite you eventually.

Comment: Then I'd recommend using Instruments to figure out what specifically is slowing it down: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-use-instruments-to-profile-your-swiftui-code-and-identify-slow-layouts

Comment: Well I know what is slowing it down, which is that every single time I change a property in a `Item` class, it updates the entire list

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `LazyVStack` in a `ScrollView` as long as you don't need `List` specific functionality. `List`s aren't as efficient as `LazyVStack`s yet (Apple bug).

```
ScrollView {
    LazyVStack {
        ForEach(store.items.indices) { index in
            DetailView(item: self.$store.items[index])
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This fixes the performance issue, however, I'm using the `DetailView` inside of a `NavigationView`, and so it doesn't really work.

Comment: Confirmed with iOS 15 and Xcode 13.2.1. Switching from List to ScrollView + LazyVStack immediately solved the performance *and* NavigationLink still works to detail views